# How to configure apache to support websockets

Tags: python, apache, websocket

I wrote server in python and now I would like to configure apache web server to support websockets. 
My server returns information when a client sends queries to these addresses:

```
def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/playgame", EmptyGame),
        (r"/playgame/", EmptyGame),
        (r"/playgame/(.*)", PlayerGameWebsocket)
    ])
```

How to configure the server to support regular user traffic but also to enable websockets when the client establishes such a connection?

I user apache2.4 server.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it turned out that the solution is trivial. If someone ever looked for an answer, just add a simple redirection to the application in the virtual host configuration which listens on localhost:

```
ProxyPassMatch "/playgame/(.*)" "ws://127.0.0.1:8888/playgame/$1"
ProxyPassReverse "/playgame/(.*)" "ws://127.0.0.1:8888/playgame/$1"
```

Thanks to such syntax, we can even pass additional data, e.g. "/playgame/123".
We connect from the client without specifying the port:

```
var adr = "ws://serverip/playgame/" + gameid;
var ws = new WebSocket(adr);
```